# I need a query that will get the sum(column) with 4 different where conditions which includes group by condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my query:

```
SELECT
    date,
    (SELECT sum(sessions) as org FROM datatwo WHERE medium='Organic Search' GROUP by date),
    (SELECT sum(sessions) as soc FROM datatwo WHERE medium='Social' GROUP BY date),
    (SELECT sum(sessions) as dir FROM datatwo WHERE medium='Direct' group by date),
    (SELECT sum(sessions) as ref FROM datatwo WHERE medium='Referral')
FROM datatwo
GROUP BY date
```

I am trying to combine 4 queries in a single query but I am getting this error, I am using mysql DB.

> 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the result of a query as a column, it must return exactly one row and one column. Expressions like this:

```
(SELECT sum(sessions) as org FROM datatwo WHERE medium='Organic Search' GROUP by date)
```

will return one row for every distinct `date` value.

I suspect you want this:

```
SELECT
    date,
    sum(case when medium='Organic Search' then sessions end) as org,
    sum(case when medium='Social' then sessions end) as soc,
    sum(case when medium='Direct' then sessions end) as dir,
    sum(case when medium='Referral' then sessions end) as ref
FROM datatwo
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: I need this data to plot a graph so, I need the row for every distinct date value how to do it

Comment: @test see edited answer for a possible solution. You would benefit from some SQL tutorials.

Comment: Thanks @bohemian you are really an sql guru, It worked for me Can you please refer me some tutorials

Comment: No problem. There's always https://www.w3schools.com/sql/. I haven't looked at it though, so I can't vouch for it. Try googling "SQL Tutorial" and find something you like.

Comment: Once again Thanks @bohemian